# dictionary to Codable in swift

Tags: ios, swift, codable

string value:

```
Optional("{\n  \"WebResponse\": {\n    \"HasError\": \"FALSE\",\n    \"ResponseMessage\": \"Signed in Successfully.\",\n    \"Result\": \"SUCCESS\",\n    \"ResultData\": {\n      \"C\": {\n        \"CustomerId\": \"656\",\n        \"CustomerName\": \"swift son\",\n        \"UserName\": \"swift@infinx.com\",\n        \"Type\": \"FORM\",\n        \"OldGCMID\": \"eA5RV0TSCoY:APA91bFea67cIlKlVes6Scdgth4CiHSzpk78hE89953-l6gK4O9xflYAs0p24jzccBtqQgAMoRaEM4SOdJ1546QDtYk2nm64cZurwz58c9Pmww4JLRDA7wtWSktpdFdVkX94VoiSCPdm\",\n        \"GCMID\": \"\",\n        \"LoyaltyPoint\": \"0\",\n        \"CorporateId\": \"19\",\n        \"U\": {\n          \"EmailVerified\": \"1\"\n        }\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}")
```

json response:

```
{
WebResponse =     {
    HasError = FALSE;
    ResponseMessage = "Signed in Successfully.";
    Result = SUCCESS;
    ResultData =         {
        C =             {
            CorporateId = 19;
            CustomerId = 656;
            CustomerName = "swift son";
            GCMID = "";
            LoyaltyPoint = 0;
            OldGCMID = "eA5RV0TSCoY:APA91bFea67cIlKlVes6Scdgth4CiHSzpk78hE89953-l6gK4O9xflYAs0p24jzccBtqQgAMoRaEM4SOdJ1546QDtYk2nm64cZurwz58c9Pmww4JLRDA7wtWSktpdFdVkX94VoiSCPdm";
            Type = FORM;
            U =                 {
                EmailVerified = 1;
            };
            UserName = "swift@infinx.com";
        };
    };
};
}
```

my models:

```
struct CData:Codable {
var corporateId:String
var customerId:String
var customerName:String
var gCMID:String
var loyaltyPoint:String
var oldGCMID:String
var types:String
var userName:String

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case corporateId = "CorporateId"
    case customerId = "CustomerId"
    case customerName = "CustomerName"
    case gCMID = "GCMID"
    case loyaltyPoint = "LoyaltyPoint"
    case oldGCMID = "OldGCMID"
    case types = "Types"
    case userName = "UserName"
}
```

}

```
struct ResultData: Codable {
var resultData: CData

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
       case resultData = "ResultData"
   }
 }


struct WebResponse: Codable {
    var HasError: Bool
    var ResponseMessage: String
    var Result: String
    var ResultData: ResultData


    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case HasError = "HasError"
        case ResponseMessage = "ResponseMessage"
        case Result = "Result"
        case ResultData = "ResultData"
    }
    }


when I covert this response to data and put it in model using

    let jsonRes = try JSONDecoder().decode(WebResponse.self, from: dataFromString)
                                print(jsonRes)
```

to give me error

> keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "HasError", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"HasError\", intValue: nil) (\"HasError\").", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: am I doing the right way ?

Comment: Don't post the NSDictionary log, post the string from `dataFromString`. Because `json response:` isn't JSON, it's the log of a NSDictionary, potentially already a JSON passed through JSONSerialization.

Comment: I have converted the data to NSDictionary to see that dictionary  using  JSONSerialization to check the output

Comment: But it we'd want to replicate easily your code, it would be easier to give the JSON String (more Playground-able)

Comment: @Larme I made the changes u can see in the question now thanks

Comment: you are missing parsing `C`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HasError` isn't a direct sub of the main  json , You need

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let webResponse: WebResponse

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case webResponse = "WebResponse"
    }
}

// MARK: - WebResponse
struct WebResponse: Codable {
    let hasError:String
    let responseMessage, result: String
    let resultData: ResultData

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case hasError = "HasError"
        case responseMessage = "ResponseMessage"
        case result = "Result"
        case resultData = "ResultData"
    }
}

// MARK: - ResultData
struct ResultData: Codable {
    let c: C

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case c = "C"
    }
}

// MARK: - C
struct C: Codable {
    let corporateID, customerID: Int
    let customerName, gcmid: String
    let loyaltyPoint: Int
    let oldGCMID, type: String
    let u: U
    let userName: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case corporateID = "CorporateId"
        case customerID = "CustomerId"
        case customerName = "CustomerName"
        case gcmid = "GCMID"
        case loyaltyPoint = "LoyaltyPoint"
        case oldGCMID = "OldGCMID"
        case type = "Type"
        case u = "U"
        case userName = "UserName"
    }
}

// MARK: - U
struct U: Codable {
    let emailVerified: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case emailVerified = "EmailVerified"
    }
}
```

---

Decode

```
let jsonRes = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: dataFromString)
```

Comment: There is twice the `struct WebResponse`. Author didn't parse the top level.

Comment: thanks for your ans but it shows : typeMismatch(Swift.Bool, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "WebResponse", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "HasError", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Bool but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: change `let hasError:String`